# Writing a function that sorts by low powers while ignoring higher powers of various variables

Tags: physics, sorting

I'm writing a Mathematica code with the aim of automating operator mixing calculations in QCD (at least at one-loop order). So far, it can generate Feynman rules and all graphs, assign the rules, call FeynCalc to perform algebraic manipulations in dim. reg., identify integrals and replace with an instance of the master integrals, and expand about small $\epsilon$, where $d=4-2\epsilon$ is the spacetime dimension. Now I would like it to identify tree-level structures for the mixing portion.

As an example, suppose I have three operators, $O_1$, $O_2$, and $O_3$. When considering the fermionic two-point functions, these have tree-level structures which are linear combinations of $m^2$, $p^2$, and $imp_{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}$ (lower indices because of Euclidean metric). Then any fermionic two-point function will be given as
$\Gamma_i=f(m^2,p^2)m^2 + g(m^2,p^2) p^2 + h(m^2,p^2) im p_{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}$,
where the coefficient functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ may generically depend on dimensionless combinations of $m^2$ and $p^2$, for example, like

$$
f(m^2,p^2)=\frac{1}{\epsilon}+\log\left(\frac{4\pi\mu^2}{\gamma'p^2}\right)+\frac{m^2}{p^2}\log\left(\frac{m^2}{m^2+p^2}\right)+\cdots,
$$

where the first term is the pole relevant to renormalization, the second term is related to the scaling behavior, and the remaining terms are "finite parts" related to the renormalized correlation function. These latter terms are the problematic parts for me. What I would like to do is take any output from the finished portion of my code and express it as $\Gamma$ above. I cannot simply differentiate, because the coefficient functions depend on $m^2$ and $p^2$. Similarly, I cannot just use the built-in `Coefficient` function, because, for example, things like this can happen:

```
Coefficient[expr,m,2] = 3 Imp / p^2 +...
```

which should be a finite part of the function $h$ (`Imp` represents $im p_{\mu}\gamma_{\mu}$).

Is there a clean way to project out te functions $f$, $g$, and $h$ as I've outlined here?

Thank you in advance!

**Update**

Here is the compressed Mathematica output for an example correlation function:

```
Uncompress[\!\(TraditionalForm\`"\<1:\
eJy9lb1OwzAQgFOcQth4Bd4AXLF0bEUlpA5RxchSpKayVJMIg5B4dsD4HLmJTZ1z/\
lhOcs65++7X18/\
5JkuiKBKxEunhXWRncJoq8cj4TjB9BFHQ7NxSlTfh5832jeUv2wObqAO7gs9EiSVdVdbS/\
GP3KuDCXtssNT6vxHjl1FV9SSkNkGMdjiljP+qGbV6DCcB/mt/\
MFvfZBRbJt7IRGEkoTKUyIKs7JnHWBGMlbbNuQ3LqVRW0BtglzxNDtc73pp5oF42Q+\
2OfaSAQ6wpz+\
RdTmfzfFqknrSvx5YDENoRnFGXzKFrd45jqPcH1BIR50Mz6lwdelMk6WtcOp1j+\
IBqWnJiV5gEzJQbXn/wW2waDNx7HqxNSAem0KZou/\
RrELdothII4fYBuk57bsdMKdyGHXOHNJT3FWg+DBIx1bLyo6SGeiVfz1XfND1kYb+\
ZH26UjVKzvinQHNHhFou3Z+uEY8SFwKxwa5S+KfGTg\>"\)]
```

In the uncompressed version, there are variables `m2`,`p2`, and `Imp`, corresponding respectively to $m^2$, $p^2$, and $imp_\mu\gamma_\mu$. Notice that there is a term that goes as $\frac{m2^2}{p2}$. This should be a finite bit proportional to `m2` (something like $m2\frac{m2}{p2}$). Likewise, the terms proportional to $Imp\frac{m2}{p2}$ should be sorted into $h$, the coefficient of `Imp`. More generally, I would like to be able to appropriately sort all higher powers of $\frac{m2}{p2}$ as well (e.g. $m2\frac{m2^n}{p2^n}$, $p2\frac{m2^n}{p2^n}$, and $Imp\frac{m2^n}{p2^n}$ for any $n$).

Comment: It would probably help if you could supply a sample of the actual output from Mathematica, so users could work with that directly. I.e. one or more examples of "expr" above, so users could examine the FullForm and see the internal structure, which is necessary for things like pattern matching. A suitable set of  patterns might be one way to achieve your goal.

Comment: Ah, I'm sorry; that makes sense. I have updated my question to include an example.

Comment: I'm still not sure what is wanted. You might try this. Replace `m2` with `p2*dc` where `dc` denotes "dimensionless constant". Then expand using `Series` to get terms in powers of `dc`. If `ee` is your original expression, something like this:`ee2 = ee /. m2 -> dc*p2;

cl = CoefficientList[Series[ee2, {dc, 0, 2}], dc]`

Answer (score 1):

If I decompress your example and assign it to "ampl", then I can run the following code on it:

```
gatherTerms[expr_]:=
    Module[{split,f,g,h,q},
        split = Collect[Expand@expr,{Imp,p2}];
        h = Cases[split,c_ Imp :> c,Infinity];
        g = Cases[split,c_ p2 :> c,Infinity];
        split = Simplify[expr - Flatten[{g,h}] . {p2,Imp}];
        f = Cases[Collect[split,m2],c_ m2^_. :> c,Infinity];
        {f,g,h}
    ];

fgh = gatherTerms[ampl]
```

[image]

All the terms were accounted for:

```
fgh[[1]] . {m2, m2^2} + fgh[[2]] p2 + 
  fgh[[3]] Imp - {ampl} // Simplify
(* {0} *)
```

For the example you provided, this works. I'm not sure how it will handle other cases. Handling Imp and p2 is straightforward because they only appear to the first power. For m2, I first removed the terms already processed, ran Collect on the remaining terms, and used a different pattern in Case because there are terms in both m2 and m2^2 to deal with. If you encounter situations where Imp or p2 appear with powers, similar modifications might be necessary for these terms as well. It depends on how representative this case is of the general problem.